# How to adjust the scale of imshow plots to keep y axis constant in subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have several numpy arrays I am plotting with `imshow`. They all have the same vertical size but different horizontal sizes. I would like to adapt the aspect to be non-scalar and proportional to my horizontal size (x axis).

To formulate differently, I have numpy array A which is 100x200 and numpy array B which is 100x300. I want in my subplot that x axis of array B three times longer than array A.

Aspect value in `imshow` takes only scalar value, and of course my proportion are not integral numbers. I have tried to adjust subplot sizes but no success so far.

In other words, I want to have aspect values in `imshow` equal to the ratio of my 2D array `shape[1]/shape[0]`. With non-scalar numbers.

Comment: Are the numpy arrays images or just data?

Comment: Just data that I plot with matshow actually

Comment: Consider using [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on using pcolormesh, but what will be the difference with matshow?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure your application, but `pcolormesh` is more suited for actual spatial data, with the origin being placed in the bottom left by default. Maybe it's not what you're looking for since you didn't share any context. In your question, you asked about `imshow`, which is intended to be used for images, as the name suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `width_ratios` arg of the [`plt.subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) call:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr1 = np.random.rand(100, 200)
arr2 = np.random.rand(100, 300)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, width_ratios=[arr1.shape[1], arr2.shape[1]])

ax1.imshow(arr1, aspect="equal")
ax2.imshow(arr2, aspect="equal")

plt.show()
```

[image: plots]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, looks quite good, except that I would like to 2 rows and 1 column, instead of 1 row and 2 columns. And then, I cannot use width_ratios anymore neither height_ratios because I want the height to be constant while the width is proportional to actual array width.

Comment: Without you sharing code I can only make assumptions. Look into [`GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html).

Comment: That's fine. I will check gridspec. I could share the code but difficult to share the data, so it does not make much sense. Thanks anyway for your input!

Comment: Fine, post another question if you can't make it work. And check the StackOverflow tutorial on ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For the data, just use mock data as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr1 = np.random.rand(100, 200)
arr2 = np.random.rand(100, 300)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2)

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_anchor('W')

axes[0].imshow(arr1, aspect="equal")
axes[1].imshow(arr2, aspect="equal")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Looks like that's what I want, thanks!